# @ModelAttribute("") annotation is still working with the wrong parameter in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model, modelattribute

I am trying to learn spring mvc. I have trouble understanding how @ModelAttribute works. Below is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/showForm")
public String showForm(Model theModel){

    Student student = new Student();
    theModel.addAttribute("testName",student); 
    return "student-form";
}

@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("hello") Student student){

    return "student-confirmation";
}
```

When i go to student-form page i create a **student** object and add it to the model with attribute name **"testName"**. Then i submit to form to "processForm" method. Using below form

```
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="testName">
    First Name: <form:input path="firstName" />
    Second Name: <form:input path="lastName" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form:form>
```

Here is what i don`t understand the attribute names do not match at where i put the object to model and where i retrive it. But the result is shown correctly..

```
theModel.addAttribute("testName",student);   //Here it is testName
@ModelAttribute("hello")  Student student    //Here it is hello
```

student-confirmation.jsp

```
First Name :  ${hello.firstName}
Last Name :  ${hello.lastName}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Student model is populated automatically after submit the form because you have set testName as the model attribute:

```
theModel.addAttribute("testName",student);
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="testName">
<form:input path="firstName" />
```

So Spring matches Student field **firstName** with form text input with path: **path="firstName"** .

**After submit:**

```
@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("hello") Student student){
```

> @ModelAttribute("hello") is not required, Student is matched
>   automatically.

You just change the reference name of the model. And then you can get values from the model using ${**hello**.firstName} at your JSP.

More info about @ModelAttribute you can read [@ModelAttribute Annotation As a Method Argument](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation)

Hope it helps.